# Comparing my array works until the array has multiple values in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to pass an array of multiple values to a function that will check if the values exist in a list of divs, and if so, mark them with a red background.

My code works when I pass an arbitrary string as a parameter, and it works when I have an array with only one value in it. However, once my array has two or more values in it, it seems to break, and there's no info in the console to clue me in.

I believe the issue is with how I wrote the comparison function, but it could also lie with how I am passing the array.

```js
var postList = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
var userList = new Array();

//compares the user's keyword entries to the text in the divs, and marks "matching" divs with a red background
function listComparison(collection, searchText) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
            collection[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }
}

//adds user entries to an array on click and clears out the textarea
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var listEntry = document.getElementById("listEntries").value;
    userList.push(listEntry);
    document.getElementById("listEntries").value = "";
    console.log(userList);
})

//event listener for the button that runs the collectionContains function above
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
    listComparison(postList, userList);
});
```

```css
div {
    background: #d0dbe6;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}

#list {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter words here one at a time and click 'Add to Filter'" id="listEntries"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="save" for="listEntries">Add to Filter</button>
<button id="run">Run Filter</button>

<div class="post">religion</div>
<div class="post">cats</div>
<div class="post">hotdogs</div>
<div class="post">babies</div>
<div class="post">test me please</div>
<div class="post">filler</div>
<div class="post">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="post">your mom</div>
<div class="post">religion again</div>
<div class="post">build a wall</div>
<div class="post">no it's becky</div>
<div class="post">anything with religions in it is screwed!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you're passing an array to [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (as in `collection[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText)`). That function expects a string as the search term, and not an array.

What's happening is that your array is getting converted into a string. When your array contains only a single string and no other elements, it works because its string representation is that same string. But when your array contains more than one element, its string representation is a comma-separated list of all those strings, and that's not going to compare correctly.

You will need to loop through the array in order to search the items in your collection for each of the strings in the array (I've renamed the parameter to make it clear you're passing an array):

```js
var postList = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
var userList = new Array();

//compares the user's keyword entries to the text in the divs, and marks "matching" divs with a red background
function listComparison(collection, searchList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchList.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < collection.length; j++) {
            if (collection[j].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchList[i]) > -1) {
                collection[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
        }
    }
}

//adds user entries to an array on click and clears out the textarea
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var listEntry = document.getElementById("listEntries").value;
    userList.push(listEntry);
    document.getElementById("listEntries").value = "";
    console.log(userList);
})

//event listener for the button that runs the collectionContains function above
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
    listComparison(postList, userList);
});
```

```css
div {
    background: #d0dbe6;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}

#list {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter words here one at a time and click 'Add to Filter'" id="listEntries"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="save" for="listEntries">Add to Filter</button>
<button id="run">Run Filter</button>

<div class="post">religion</div>
<div class="post">cats</div>
<div class="post">hotdogs</div>
<div class="post">babies</div>
<div class="post">test me please</div>
<div class="post">filler</div>
<div class="post">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="post">your mom</div>
<div class="post">religion again</div>
<div class="post">build a wall</div>
<div class="post">no it's becky</div>
<div class="post">anything with religions in it is screwed!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very tricky that there's a `String.prototype.indexOf()` and an `Array.prototype.indexOf()`; that messed with my head. I'm also not used to having to nest for loops directly inside for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var userList = new Array();

//compares the user's keyword entries to the text in the divs, and marks "matching" divs with a red background
function listComparison(collection, searchText) {
  collection.filter(function(elem) {
    return !!searchText.filter(function(text) {
      return elem.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
    }).length;
  }).forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}

//adds user entries to an array on click and clears out the textarea
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var listEntry = document.getElementById("listEntries");
  userList.push(listEntry.value);
  listEntry.value = "";
  console.log(userList);
})

//event listener for the button that runs the collectionContains function above
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var collection = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("post"));
  listComparison(collection, userList);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #d0dbe6;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
#list {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter words here one at a time and click 'Add to Filter'" id="listEntries"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="save" for="listEntries">Add to Filter</button>
<button id="run">Run Filter</button>

<div class="post">religion</div>
<div class="post">cats</div>
<div class="post">hotdogs</div>
<div class="post">babies</div>
<div class="post">test me please</div>
<div class="post">filler</div>
<div class="post">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="post">your mom</div>
<div class="post">religion again</div>
<div class="post">build a wall</div>
<div class="post">no it's becky</div>
<div class="post">anything with religions in it is screwed!</div>
```

Comment: That approach introduces a bit of a regression my existing functionality, in that it no longer applies the matching to all instances of a string, but only the first one (e.g. adding "religion" to the list in your example no longer highlights all entries with "religion" in them). +1 though, for technically solving the problem of my multi-value array not working.

Comment: The problem with flipping the condition like that is that searching for partial keywords no longer works. For example entering "dogs" will not match "hotdogs", because the latter cannot possibly appear within the former. This may or may not be an issue depending on the asker's requirements, but I *highly* doubt the asker expects users to enter "anything with religions in it is screwed!" just to match that last item.

Comment: Yes if you need partial match you need to check every string, I just modified the code a little bit (with a more functional approach - avoiding the loops inside loops, and loops in general). It is better to convert the DOM node list into a real array.

Also you can get collection on every click in this case if there was a new elem added it will be filtered as well and you will have one more less global variable.